# How to get Form Values in JQTouch:

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

HIi friends,

i working on a IPhone Web App as its kinda new to me, have studied some basics of JQuery,

i want to get the form value in one view and to return to next view,i have tried this one,

```
$("button:#Get").click(function () {

$('#msg').html($('input:textbox').val());

});
```

it works with JQuery but not in JQTouch.

Any Ideas People,

Thank u,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQTouch isn't essentially very different from a normal jQuery Js-based app. If you can set `ID`'s on your form elements you can access them the usual way.

Demonstration:

1. Go to the demo at http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main with a WebKit based desktop browser, click "User Interface' -> 'Forms' and open up your developer tools.
2. Type something into the topmost text field. Now go to the console in the developer tools and write `$('#some_name')`. You should see a normal jQuery node.
3. Type `$('#some_name').val()`. You will see the text you typed in (2).

Try some more experiments, you'll see that it works much the same as a normal jQuery-based web app.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess:

```
$("#Get").click(function() {
  $('#msg').html( $('#specificInputfield').val() );
});
```

I think you need to specify which value of which input field you want to select, because your current selector will select all text input fields.

Comment: Thanks but,i have tried to pass specific textBox value even it not works,i want u notice that i m using JQTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'tap' instead of 'click'?